# static generic method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have this java method signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Queue<T> naturalMergeSort(Queue<T> input)
```

what would the C# equivalent be?

Comment: I didnt downvote you, but i'd imagine that it was because while your whole signature might be difficult to google, the individual parts are very available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# equivalent would be:

```
public static Queue<T> naturalMergeSort<T>(Queue<T> input) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Note that in C# the interface is `IComparable<T>` instead of `Comparable<T>`, and the generic argument goes at the end of the method name as well.

Comment: @user3559599 Can you be more specific?  See my update for a few notes.

Comment: Never mind it works now, visual studio was being stupid for a second

Comment: You also would likely change the name to `NaturalMergeSort` as C# uses `PascalCasing` for method names but java uses `camelCasing` for method names in their respective naming standards.

Answer (score 0):

in c# it would be as below:

```
public static Queue<T> NaturalMergeSort<T>(Queue<T> input) where T : IComparable<T>{}
```

Comment: Why have a `where T` when you dont use `T` in the declaration?

Comment: @DStanley, should have looked.  Good find.

Comment: Should be IComparable<T>, not Comparable<T>

Comment: I just changed Comparable to IComparable